# how to create range for pages (from 1 page to x)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url="https://bararanonline.com/letter/%D5%A1?page=1"
response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
words=soup.find_all('a',"word-href")
for word in words:
  print(word.text)
```

So, I got the first page. Now, I want to scrape information from all pages and I have to put URL page number in {} (page={}), but I can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `for i in range(1, x)` and `response = requests.get("https://bararanonline.com/letter/ա", params={"page": i})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply define a for loop and set your `range()` parameters:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url="https://bararanonline.com/letter/%D5%A1?page="

words = []

for i in range(1, 3):
    response=requests.get(f'{url}{i}')
    ##or as olvin roght mentioned by setting params
    ##response=requests.get("https://bararanonline.com/letter/ա", params={"page": i})
    soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    words.extend([word.text.strip() for word in soup.find_all('a',"word-href")])

words
```

Alternativ is to go by `while` - Example starts with 207 just to show, that it stops, if there is no next page, but you can change it if you like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url="https://bararanonline.com/letter/%D5%A1?page=207"

words = []

while True:
    response=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    words.extend([word.text.strip() for word in soup.find_all('a',"word-href")])
    
    if a := soup.select_one('a[rel="next"]'):
        url = a['href']
    else:
        break
words
```